# Redirect with .htaccess to .php file

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use .htaccess to redirect:

```
http://example.com/index
```

to:

```
http://example.com/index.php
```

Comment: I understand the downvotes (this question has been asked many times before), but at least leave a comment--this question is very specific and very answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your /.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: thank you! also could you tell me how to redirect it to index.php if the link does not exist?

Comment: You can use ErrorDocument 404 /index.php bellow the rewriteRule